# Can someone explain what these number means in trademark description?

Tags: intellectual-property, trademark

I was doing some trademark search in [TESS](http://tess2.uspto.gov). I sew the following description.

> Goods and Services:   IC 038. US 100 101 104. G & S: Communications
>   services -- namely, transferring of electronic messages for groups of
>   two or more people by means of a global computer network. FIRST USE:
>   19980120. FIRST USE IN COMMERCE: 19980120

While I do understand `IC 038` means international class code, I couldn't figure out what these numbers means `US 100 101 104.`

I believe its more like subclasses. But i'm not sure.

Can someone tell me where I can get that details in USPTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are for US trademark classes. You can safely ignore them. The international classes are what count.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are US classification at USPTO. Please refer to:

http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/selectnumwithtitle.htm